Is it even possible to write a notification server that fully conforms to the desktop notification specification (DNS)?
As far as I've understood, some programs that send notifications, will call Notify once with replaces_id = 0 in order to get an ID assigned, and on next calls to Notify, they'll provide that replaces_id so that they can substitute the old notification.
(At least that's the behavior I'm observing for spotify from ArchLinux' AUR.)
Clearly, the notification server can be restarted independently from the programs that have sent notifications so far, so it can't know what IDs programs have stored, and when one of those programs will call Notify with replaces_id != 0, they will effectively be requesting an ID of a non-existing notification, which seems to violate one piece of the specification (see first table of the DNS),

An optional ID of an existing notification that this notification is intended to replace.

hence the question in the title.
(Also see this issue I opened for Dunst, thinking it was violating the spec.)


that fully conforms to the desktop notification specification (DNS)?

Nobody actually calls it "DNS" unless they intend to confuse the reader, so, +1 lawyering I suppose.

Clearly, the notification server can be restarted independently from the programs that have sent notifications so far

It is not expected that the notification daemon would exit; normally it is started together with the desktop environment and continues running until logout. (On-demand "bus activation" is strongly discouraged for this particular service, meaning exit-on-idle is also discouraged.) Though that's all irrelevant because notifications also stop existing as soon as they're closed or they time out, without the need to restart the entire notification daemon.

and when one of those programs will call Notify with replaces_id != 0, they will effectively be requesting an ID of a non-existing notification, which seems to violate one piece of the specification

I think it would be reasonable to interpret "optional ID of an existing notification" that if an ID of a non-existing notification was specified instead, then an <ID of an existing notification> was not specified, and therefore the call can proceed as if the replaces_id were not specified at all (defaulting to 0).
The intent of 'replaces_id' is to prevent redundant notifications from accumulating as the program status changes (and to do so in a more visually pleasing way than closing/reopening the notification), not to replace a notification for the sake of replacing a notification. In all cases, if Notify() is called, a notification needs to be shown – if it has nothing to replace or update (e.g. if the previous notification timed out or was dismissed or if the ID is bogus for any other reason), then a new notification should appear instead of the call outright failing.
(Practically speaking, it's simpler code-wise for a client to unconditionally update its stored ID after every call to Notify() than to explicitly check whether it has an ID stored already – and that's also what libnotify (the primary client implementation) does – so even if Notify() returns a different ID than the original for whatever reason, it's more likely to work than not.)
